# SpeechRecognition module not importing into program

Tags: python, import, speech-recognition

So I was working on an AI voice assistant and I tried importing the speech_recognition module into my code but it didn't work.
I installed the module using:

> pip install SpeechRecognition

It got installed correctly.
Then when I tried to import the module using:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```

The name of the module wasn't auto suggested or highlighted while typing so I'm assuming the interpreter was unable to find the module.
And none of the functions I called got highlighted either and gave an error on execution. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is two ways of trying to solve this

1- Try Restarting your Editor

2- Try this:

> python -m pip install SpeechRecognition

then restart the Editor.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. All I had to do was restart the editor